# He doesn’t love her half as he pretends

Tags: as

> **He doesn’t love her half as he pretends.**

Is something wrong with that sentence? Why? Because of "half"?

As I know it, the version *"He doesn’t love her half as much as he pretends."* is more common.

Comment: In your version, _half_ has nothing to refer to.

Comment: But also because this use of _as_ is correlative, and requires another _as_ before it.